# Setting a thread ID

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

I want to be able to set my own thread IDs, so for example, for the four threads I create in an application, I want to have their ID as 0, 1, 2 and 3. I know you can use a thread local variable and assign it the ID. However, for some reason, I can't use thread local variable. You could say, passing thread ID as argument to the thread function could do the trick, but in that case you need to pass the thread ID in every function used by the thread, which is ofcourse not viable.

A little searching on google showed me **set_tid_address**, that looks interesting by its name, but I'm not sure if it could fulfill my purpose, as its documentation is not clear. Any ideas, how to achieve this?

Comment: You can't control the thread IDs; they are controlled by the system.

Comment: Can't you map from the real thread id to your private thread id instead? Setting the thread id might make it clash with an existing thread id and will make for endless hours of fun debugging it. ;)

Comment: @Joachim, Yes this can be one way. I already thought about it, but I want a more direct way.

Comment: what is wrong with passing it to every function?  You will most likely need to pass some kind of context structure to all functions involved in that thread anyways.  Especially since you can't use thread local vars.

Answer (score 2):

PIDs are kernel managed, using - on my kernel - a pidmap_array bitmap. More or less, the next PID will be the last increased by one (until round robin going back to start, as needed). Except for private remapping as suggested above, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: The only limited impact you have - and this is obviously not what you want - is to change the value of the maximum PID assignable on your system (in 2.6 kernel, PID_MAX_DEFAULT). It's usually found in /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Pass in a structure to each thread you create (normally as a pointer) and then have them fill in the thread ID and other attributes as necessary - it can also be used for supplying parameters.
2. Have a mapping which maps between your logical "thread numbers" and "thread IDs"

Answer (score 0):

> for some reason, I can't use thread local variable

Figure out the reason, and eliminate it.

Otherwise you are practicing "[Programming by coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence)".

Comment: He might mean that he's not going to use thread locals because, for example, they are not portable enough.

Comment: And `set_tid_address` that he is proposing to use will be more portable?